# Get all documents of a collection spends read for each document?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore

I have a React app that one of the collections have more than 3.000 documents.
My quota is spending too fast.

When I use onSnapshot() or get() to get the 3.000 documents I'am spending my quota for each document that is read?

If so, there is a way to get the documents spending only 1 read?

Comment: When you say collections what type of data, is this a large object or the size of the document? Also what do you you mean spending? Are you referring to bandwidth?

Comment: Can you just do a get() directly on the collection to return the entire thing (including documents) in one read?

Comment: Neil, The collection that i'm saying have several documents (is a list of products). And when I said spending I i'm refering to the counts of writes and reads that Firestore limits for use.

Hi Jered! When I use the get() to return 3000 documents Firebase counts 3000 reads or just 1 read?

Comment: if you retrieve 3000 documents it counts 3000 reads (per user)... if 3 users load your app with that query, 9000 reads go there... and the onSnapshot is expensive if you make a lot of updates, since are making updates you are spending writes, and every user who listing those changes is consuming a read...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are not any workarounds, if you query the whole collection you are paying for each doc (1 doc is 1 read) per user who make the query... probably you should architect your application in a way where you don't need to query all your data at once or maybe using pagination.

[This article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) can get you started with pagination.

Or maybe, firebase is not the right tool for your business case.